# How can I detect if a file exists?

Tags: c, windows, filesystems

I'm programming in C and trying to write portable code.

My question is, how can I tell if a file exists and is readable?

I am currently using the code:

```
   f = fopen(filename, "r");
   if (f) printf("File exists!");
```

In my program, `filename` is set by the user, and should be considered as untrusted input (e.g. `filename` could be maliciously crafted).

My issue is that the above code is not robust. For example, when used on windows with the filename "PRN" it will print "File exists!" even though no such file exists on the filesystem.

I know I could filter out the reserved filenames on Windows, as there is only about a dozen of them, but that feels like a hack. Also, I only know what I know. Maybe there are other "reserved" or "special" names that I don't know about.

Is there any simple and portable way to determine if a file exists in C?

Alternatively, if I have to use an OS API, which function should I use?

Comment: Just FYI: Portable code is a myth. There are applications which are ported successfully, but really there is nothing called universally portable.

Comment: Attempting to open the file is one of the most reliable and portable ways to see whether the file can be opened.  It typically isn't subject to the TOCTOU (Time Of Check, Time Of Use) attacks that alternatives such as using `access()` or `stat()` or `lstat()` are vulnerable to.  And those alternatives are POSIX-specific which may limit their usefulness for you.

Comment: You probably want one of the [File Management Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/file-management-functions), and probably one in the `GetFileAttributes*` family.

Comment: `"PRN"` exists because it names the printer device on MS Windows. Does `"./PRN"` also report as exists?

Comment: The question is: Why is it a problem for your task, that `PRN` would be reported as an existing file? The answer to this question might yield better suggestions

Comment: if fopen fail, you have to check if errno == ENOENT to be sure that the file doesn't exist. If there is an another error, maybe the file exist, maybe not. So you have three possible answer : yes the file exist, no he doesn't exist, i don't know I failed to check.

Comment: @jhx Yes, `"./PRN"`, `"C:\my_folder\PRN"`, and even `"PRN.jpg"` will all open with `fopen()`. Windows is weird.

Comment: @Ctx My program takes a filename as input, then attempts to open and process that file. If the user gives `COM1` as the filename, then my program attempts to read data from the serial port! Do I really need to elaborate on why I don't want that?

Comment: @Tom's I don't care if `fopen()` fails. I care that it *succeeds* when the file dosn't actually exist.

Comment: @jhx `GetFileAttributes` returns exactly the same vale for `PRN` as for a file that actually exists. I know with `GetFileAttributesEx` I can get file creation time and such, but I don't know if that will be a reliable tell.

Comment: @jim Can't you run the program in an unprivileged context, where reading from the serial port is simply not allowed?

Comment: @jim No, fopen doesn't magically succeed when the file doesn't exist. Either the file exist (try to use an absolute path) or your code is brken (then show an MCVE).

Comment: @Tom's Did you read the question? Windows has reserved filenames. If you use `fopen("COM1.jpg", "r")` on Windows, it will open a pipe to a serial port. The file `COM1.jpg` does not (and indeed isn't allow to) exist as an actual file.

Comment: @ctx Yes, I do plan on running the software in a unprivileged context. However, I would still like to address the problem programmatically if possible.

Comment: @jim Yes, so now I think I understand what you want. If you succeed to open a "file", you want to know if it's a regular file and not a pipe or another thing. Well, I think you will have to do some specific plateform code, like using "stat"on Linux and whatever the equivalent windows function. Because if you filtering on name , you will be plateform specific as PRN is a valid Unix name. So it's better to use system function to do what you want.